# How to print posts and comments with only one sql query

Tags: php, mysql, join

Is it possible to print out (PHP) all my blog posts + associated comments via one sql query?

If so, how?

I was thinking in this direction:

```
SELECT p.post_id, p.title, c.comment_body
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN comments c
ON c.parent_id = p.post_id
```

But this didn't work out as I expected

Comment: why didn't it work out as you expected?

Comment: How would you like the result to look?

Comment: You specifically marked this as mysql/join but maybe you want to try http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/PHP+Language+Center `MongoDB (from "humongous") is a scalable, high-performance, open source, schema-free, document-oriented database.`

Answer (score 4):

Using one SQL query is not very convenient, since you have 1 post and multiple comments.
Having the post details added to each comment (in a combined query) is a waste of resources.

It is much more convenient to get the post details and use `post_id` of the post to find the comments belonging to the post.

Comment: +1.  This is a situation that calls for two queries -- it's a one-to-many relationship of posts to comments.  Only if it was a one-to-one relationship, would it be advisable to try and get data from both tables with a join.

Comment: Agreed.  This is definitely a situation where it just doesn't make sense to use one query.

Comment: I need this because I want to create an XML file containing all data (all posts + 10 most recent comments/post). I don't know what the best solution is when you got 100 posts. That means you have to execute 100 sql queries?

Comment: No 2 queries are required: one to grab the post details and one to grab the comment details. When only 10 comments are required use the 'LIMIT' and 'ORDER BY' SQL statements. The results of the comment query can be read using a loop and mysql_fetch_array() or something similar (depending on your needs)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of is to iterate through all the rows returned and group them into an associative array where keys are the post IDs. Then you can iterate through that associative array and print the comments for each post, taking the post title from the first row in the group.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL you could use the [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function:

```
SELECT p.post_id, p.title, GROUP_CONCAT(c.comment_body)
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.parent_id = p.post_id
GROUP BY p.post_id
```

Answer (score 0):

When getting data just use the field name like:
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT p.post_id, p.title, c.comment_body FROM posts p LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.parent_id = p.post_id");

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['title'] . " " . $row['comment_body'];
  echo "<br />";
  }
```

From: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php

Comment: But what if there are multiple comments?

Comment: It should be $row['comment_body'][1] for the next comment

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL:

```
SELECT p.post_id, p.title, GROUP_CONCAT(c.comment_body), count(*) as coment_cnt
FROM
    posts p
        LEFT JOIN comments c ON (p.post_id = c.parent_id)
GROUP BY
    p.post_id
```

Answer (score 0):

"But this didn't work out as I expected "

...but you don't say what you did expect.

Assuming that the the implied schema in your query is correct, then its a no brainer to only show the posts once:

```
$lastpostid=false;
while ($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  if ($r['post_id']!=$lastpost) {
     print "Post: " . $r['title'] . "<br />\n";
     $comment_id=1;
     $lastpost=$r['post_id'];
  }
  print "Comment # $comment_id : " . $r['comment_body'] . "<br />\n";
  $comment_id++;
}
```

But as I said this implies that your query is correct (i.e. that comments are not hierarchical).

C.