# How to retrieve all posts with all comments using 2 SQL queries

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to make a page with a list of posts, and underneath each post all the comments belonging to that post. Initially I wanted to use just one query to retrieve all the posts + comments using the SQL's JOIN, but I find it impossible to for example retrieve a post with multiple comments. It only displays the posts with a maximum of 1 comment per post, or it just show a post multiple times depending on the amount of comments.

In this related question, somebody talked about using 2 queries:
[How to print posts and comments with only one sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049573/how-to-print-posts-and-comments-with-only-one-sql-query)

But how do I do this?

I've got the query and a while loop for posts, but I obviously don't want to run a query for comments for each post inside that loop.

```
$getPost = mysql_query('SELECT p.post_id,
                               p.user_id,
                               p.username,
                               p.content
                        FROM post p
                        ORDER BY p.post_id DESC');

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getPost)) 
{ 
... 
}
```

Table structure (reply is the table for storing comments):

```
POST (post_id (primary key), user_id, username, content, timestamp)
REPLY (reply_id (primary key), post_id, username, reply_content, timestamp)
```

Comment: Show us your table structures.

Comment: Is this a system you made or like Wordpress? If your own, more details about the tables will be helpful

Comment: i didnt understand why SQL JOIN doesnt work for you.

Comment: Added the table structures :)

Comment: You may use JOIN query. It will be easier for us to help you if you show your table structures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in a single query, which is OK if the amount of data in your original posts is **small**:

```
$getPost = mysql_query('SELECT
  p.*,
  r.reply_id, r.username r_username, r.reply_content, r.timestamp r_timestamp
  FROM post p
    left join reply r
  ORDER BY p.post_id DESC'
);

$posts = array();
$last_id = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getPost)) 
{ 
  if ($last_id != $row['post_id']) {
    $posts[] = array(
      'post_id' => $row['post_id'],
      'user_id' => $row['user_id'],
      'username' => $row['username'],
      'content' => $row['content'],
      'timestamp' => $row['timestamp'],
      'comments' => array()
    );
  }

  $posts[sizeof($posts) - 1]['comments'][] = array(
    'reply_id' => $row['reply_id'],
    'username' => $row['r_username'],
    'reply_content' => $row['reply_content'],
    'timestamp' = $row['r_timestamp']
  );
}
```

Otherwise, break it into two queries like so:

```
$getPost = mysql_query('SELECT
  p.*,
  FROM post p
  ORDER BY p.post_id DESC'
);

$rows = array();
$ids = array();
$index = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getPost)) {
  $row['comments'] = array();
  $rows[] = $row;
  $ids[] = $row['post_id'];
  $index[$row['post_id']] = sizeof($rows) - 1;
}

$getComments = mysql_query('select r.* from replies r where r.post_id in ("'
  . join('","', $ids)
  . '")');
while ($row = mysq_fetch_assoc($getComments)) {
  $rows[$index[$row['post_id']]]['comments'][] = $row;
}
```

... Or something like that. Either option allows you to litter your first query with WHERE clauses and so forth to your heart's content. The advantage of the 2nd approach is that you don't re-transmit your original post data for each comment!

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out and giving me stuff to learn. Awesome community.

Comment: The latter example is spot on. This is a common problem, and I find that utilizing two queries is the way to go for something like this- especially if the post content is large. It's better to have two quick queries than one slow query.

Answer (score 1):

In order to also get those posts without comments, you need to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. In that case, any row in the first table without any corresponding rows in the second table will be paired with a row consisting of null values.

```
SELECT *  FROM posts
LEFT OUTER JOIN comments ON posts~post_id = comments~post_id;
```

By the way: there is also a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`. When you would use that, you would get all comments, including those where the parent post got lost somehow, but no posts without comments.

Comment: I tried this, but for example: I have 1 post with 3 comments. This query displays the single post 3 times with each comment.

Comment: You won't get around that as long as you use a relational and not a hierarchical database - but it shouldn't be hard to fix that on the PHP level, when you also `SORT BY post_id`.